# QuickSort code not working

Tags: java, quicksort

I've been trying to learn how to implement quick sort. I read the basic algorithm and tried to implement my own code for it first (based off of my understanding of the algorithm).

For the sake of simplicity, I'm taking the pivot as the first element. Please ignore that if you can. My code runs but does not return the correct result and I'm not able to figure out why. Any help is much appreciated.

```
public class QuickSortMain 
{
public static void displayArray(int[] arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        System.out.print(arr[i] + "  ");
}

public static void quickSort(int[] arr)
{
    quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
}

private static void quickSort(int[] arr, int lo, int hi)
{
    if(lo >= hi) return;

    int j = lo;
    int left = lo;
    int right = hi;

    while(arr[left] <= arr[j])
        left++;

    while(arr[right] >= arr[j])
        right--;

    if (left >= right) return;

    swap(arr, left, right);
    swap(arr, j, left);

    quickSort(arr, lo, j-1);
    quickSort(arr, j+1, hi);
}

private static void swap(int[] arr, int i1, int i2)
{
    int temp = arr[i1];
    arr[i1] = arr[i2];
    arr[i2] = temp;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int[] myArray = {14, 79, 11, 42, 3, 27, 192, 44, 26, 742, 129};
    System.out.println(myArray.length);
    System.out.println("Original Array:");
    displayArray(myArray);

    quickSort(myArray);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Sorted Array:");
    displayArray(myArray);

}
}
```

Here is the output I get:
11
Original Array:
14  79  11  42  3  27  192  44  26  742  129
Sorted Array:
3  14  11  42  79  27  192  44  26  742  129

Thanks!

Comment: What you have already tried in order to debug your code?

Comment: The _partitioning part_ is broken. Move it to a separate method. It makes the code readable, and easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that all the values that are less than the pivot are on one side
and all the values greater are on the other. You were not doing enough swaps in the partition method.

To solve situations like this I recommend you write test cases to highlight the areas that the algorithm is not working. Also using the debugger helps.

```
private static void quickSort(int[] arr, int lo, int hi)
{
    if(lo >= hi) return;

    int j = lo;
    int left = lo;
    int right = hi;

    while (left < right){
        left++;
        while(arr[left] < arr[j] && (left < right))
            left++;

        while(arr[right] > arr[j] && (left < right))
            right--;

        if (left < right){
            swap(arr, left, right);
        }
    }

    if(arr[left] < arr[j]){
        swap(arr, j, left);
    }

    quickSort(arr, lo, left-1);
    quickSort(arr, left, hi);
}
```

Comment: Okay, once we've swapped arr[left] and arr[right], they are in their "right places." That is, arr[left] now contains something less than arr[j] and arr[right] contains something greater than a[j]. Then why do we swap arr[j] and arr[left - 1] (considering that arr[left] is less than arr[j] and we're placing arr[j] right before arr[left])?